# Async push notification to Microsoft Authenticator App

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have created a Office 365 developer account . In the acount I have created a normal user (user1) .The user1 has been configured to authenticate with password and also push notification will be sent to his mobile Microsoft authenticator app .

is it possible to send an async push notification to the users Microsoft authenticator app . I mean has Azure AD has exposed any api using whi
ch we can send push notifications to the users Microsoft authenticator app (without user even initiating anything )

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

At this point of time there is no such API to push notifications to authenticator  app which can be able  happen without interaction or initiation.

You can give your idea or suggestion as feedback at [https://feedback.azure.com/](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/22920db1-ad25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789).